# Why is the controller executed twice (flashbag, redirectoroute)?

Tags: php, symfony

I have two routes /alpha and /beta configured in yml. In alphaAction a notice is placed in the flashbag and a redirecttoroute occurs. In betaAction the notice in the flashbag is read.

Sometimes I get 2 notices when I try /alpha in the browser and sometimes I get one notice.

Can someone explain what is happening, what I'm doing wrong.

```
public function alphaAction()
{
  $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add("notice",mt_rand());
  return $this->redirectToRoute("beta");
}

public function betaAction()
{
  $notices= $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->get('notice');    
  return new Response(implode($notices,", "));
}
```

Comment: `$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add("notice",mt_rand());` in Symfony 2.6 and above can be done as `$this->addFlash('notice', mt_rand());`  Are you sure the times you get it twice it isn't because an error has occurred and you have just refresh the browser?

Comment: I tried the shortened notation (addFlash) and still get similar results.  I don't do a refresh in the browser, I just retype http://localhost:8000/alpha and press the Enter-key.  The result in /beta is between 1 and 3 (different) random numbers.

Comment: Do you ever see the same numbers repeated on the `betaAction()`?

Comment: No.  The behaviour is highly feckle.  From time to time I get 1 random result in notice, and suddenly it starts misbehaving.  For some reason  the easiest way to start getting 2 results in stead of 1 is calling the beta-route twice.  But the results are always unrelated random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `add` method I could reproduce the issues you described. This can be fixed by using the `set` method and not the `add` (or `setFlash`) method.

```
public function alphaAction()
{
  $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set("notice",mt_rand());
  return $this->redirectToRoute("beta");
}

public function betaAction()
{
  $notices= $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->get('notice');    
  return new Response(implode($notices,", "));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Are you sure that alphaAction is now only executed once?  Could it be that alphaAction is still executed multiple times and the value in notice gets overwritten?

Comment: If you now try and access the beta route direct you get nothing which implies alpha is not being called

Comment: I still think alpha is executed twice.  I tried logging the generated numbers with monolog and get two numbers in app/dev.log in stead of one.  
    $a=mt_rand();
    $logger = $this->get('logger');
    $logger->debug("_*_*".$a);
    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set("notice",$a);
    return $this->redirectToRoute("beta");